# label Hide and show using xaml and mvvvm

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android

How to Lable Hide and show if admin is login then one label is displayed otherwise label is hidden {How Solve it} ?

> xaml Code

```
 <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsAdminTrue}">
<Label Text="is_professional"></Label>
 </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel Code

```
public void IsProfessional()
    {
        if (CurrentUser.IsAdmin!= true)
        {
            IsAdminTrue= false;
        }
        else
        {
            IsAdminTrue= true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to hide the label or show yes or no for is professional? Why are you changing visibility of stack layout? You need change it for label right ?

Comment: What's the code for IsAdminTrue (bad name btw)? Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your view model? Are you sending a PropertyChanged event on the IsAdminTrue setter?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void IsProfessional()
{
    if (CurrentUser.IsAdmin!= true)
    {
            lblNo.Visibility= Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
            lblNo.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Here lblNo is an label.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the Visibility property on the Label, not the StackLayout.  You could either change IsAdminTrue to IsAdminVisible (of type Visibility), or you could use the BooleanToVisibility converter.  Second option is usually the preferred method.

Of course, none of this will matter if IsAdminTrue doesn't raise PropertyChanged.